# String indices must be integers in one place of code in python

Tags: python

```
import pymongo
import sys

client=pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client.rop 

try:         
     cntcur=db.albums.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$images"},"$group":"_id":"null","count":{'$sum':1}}}])
     cursor1=db.images.find()    

     for im in cursor1:         
         id1=int(im['_id'])
         cnt=0         
         cursor= db.albums.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$images"}])
         print id1         
         for image in cursor:
             print "moving to images collection"             
             ig=image['images']
             if (id1 == ig):
                break;
             else:
                cnt=cnt+1              
                if (cnt == cntr):
                   print "removing"  
                   db.images.remove({'_id':id1})  



except Exception as e:
     print "unexpected error", type(e),e
```

I get error in the line `ig=image['images']`. I tried changing it to `ig=int(image['images'])`, but I get same error.

Comment: Does cursor returns a list of `dict` objects? Try `print image` and `print type(image)`.

Comment: for print image i get "ok" and for print type(image) i get <type 'unicode'>

Comment: @ZdaR yes in pymongo it returns a dictionary with Unicode key and value

Comment: then why am i getting this error.... ? :(

Comment: @Svati did it print id1

Comment: @VigneshKalai kalai yeah it did

Comment: @Svati So after printing that it showed this error right so only one df1 is printed right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82913/discussion-between-vignesh-kalai-and-svati).

Comment: yes first it print 0 ( for print id1) then ok (for print image), then <type 'unicode'> for print type(image) and then "moving to images collection" the n finally the error message .

Comment: c:\Python27>python hw4.py
0
ok
<type 'unicode'>
moving to images collection
unexpected error <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymongo
import sys    
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=client.rop    
try:        
    cursor1=db.images.find()
    for im in cursor:
        id1=int(im['_id'])
        print id1
        cnt=0
        cursor=db.albums.find()
        for image in cursor:
            ig=image['images']
            for data in ig:
                if (id1 == data):
                    cnt=1
                    break;
        if cnt==0:
            print "removing"
            db.images.remove({'_id':id1})
except Exception as e:
    print "unexpected error",type(e) , e
```